# Change coords of line in python tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter-canvas

I've drawn a line in `tkinter.Canvas` and now I want to move one end. Is this possible, e.g. with `itemconfig`?

```
import tkinter

tk = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(tk)
canvas.pack()
line = canvas.create_line(0, 0, 100, 100)
tk.mainloop()
```

Now I want to change the end of the line to `75, 25`. Is there a better way as to delete the line and create a new one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you've created some item on canvas you can use the following methods to edit the item:

- **coords( )**
- **itemconfig( )**
- **move( )**

***For example:***

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
w = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
w.pack()
var = w.create_line(0, 0, 100, 100)
w.coords(var, 0, 0, 75, 25)
root.mainloop()
```

For learning more **about Canvas**, you may refer:

- [Tkinter Canvas Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)
- [GUI with Tk(Python3.6.5)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html)

Answer (score 1):

`canvas.coords(line, 0, 0, 75, 25)` is the solution