# What is the best way to work with images in the tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, canvas

Hello I am new at programming and I am making a tkinter project to learn.

In my project, because i didnt like the tkinter widgets, ive decided to only use the Canvas widget and draw all my program there.

To do that I am making my own widgets that will be drawn in the canvas.
What I want is a Widget that follows the following structure:

```py
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, coords, img):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.img = img

    def _redraw(self, coords):
        self.img.redraw(coords)
```

I want the Widget to store an image_object of some sort. The function _redraw will give the coordinates of the new size like so (x0, y0, x1, y1), and I want the img object to redraw itself to fit the new coordinates.

I was wondering the best way to accomplish this (in terms of space and speed), idealy I would like to work with svg files. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Image:
    def __init__(self, canvas, filePath):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.img = tk.PhotoImage(file = filePath)

    def _redraw(self, x, y):
        return self.canvas.create_image(x, y, image = self.img)

    def setScale(self, scale):
        if scale >= 1:
            self.img = self.img.zoom(int(scale))
        else:
            self.img = self.img.subsample(int(1/scale))
```

I've use it with pngs, untested with svgs.
So with pngs etc it's best to resize the images externally before loading, but the scale function works fine if that's inconvenient.

There are more options to add to create_image() like anchor etc, see the documentation.

Also, there are several ways to move the image.  One is to undraw and redraw it elsewhere (you need to keep the id returned from create_image() so that you can undraw it).  The other is to use the coords() function, see documentation, also see [Change coords of line in python tkinter canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50699664/change-coords-of-line-in-python-tkinter-canvas)

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. The only problem I see is that after making the image small when scales up again loses too much quality, I gess ill take a look at working with svgs. Another thing I dont understand is that after the setScale function is called the img disapeard without the canvas widget being deleted, do you know why?

Comment: To avoid the loss in quality, load a big picture and scale it down with a number between 0 and 1. e.g .0.5 to half the size.  Also, have you tried it with svgs?  (I didn't say svgs wouldn't work - just that i've not tried them).  After calling setScale() you need to call redraw() again, maybe that's why your image disappeared.